# I can't subscribe to facebook page real time updates api v2.0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

my question about page realtime subscriptions :
In the documentation to make an app receive a page subscriptions i should make this request :
make a post request to : page_id/tabs
params : app_id 
with a page access token.

this request not working anymore and the page don't send a page subscriptions to the callback url .
i am using API 2.0
also i can't stop a page from sending subscriptions to my callback url (in case there is a page that already sending subscriptions):
Please note that : i checked the documentation on the upgrading section 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading
in api v 2.2 there is a new call to realtime subscriptions :

so if i want to subscribe to a page i use this request :

post request => page_id/subscribed_apps
with page access token.

to delete a subscription use :
delete request => page_id/subscribed_apps
with page access token

to know what apps this page subscribed to :
get request => page_id/subscribed_apps
with page access token.

i made the above requests using api v 2.2 using graph api explorer and everything wrks fine and i started to receive subscriptions to my callback url.

Note : there is no problem in the backend code (the callback url code), it already working with v 2.2 and the old subscribed pages.

Please advice, should i upgrade my api calls to v2.2 ? or there is a working solution for 2.0 ?

Comment: Which documentation say you should do `/{page-id}/tabs`? That is wrong.

Comment: Hello @WizKid, in the link that i mentioned i qoute :

"Real Time Updates for Pages
Many apps get real time updates for changes to pages. These include comments, posts and other data. In versions previous to v2.2, this was done by adding an app to the /{page-id}/tabs app that wasn't registered as a page tab app"

Comment: This may give idea of a complete flow: http://tech-brains.blogspot.in/2015/04/real-time-updates-for-facebook-page.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up upgrading to v2.2 since based on the documentation the endpoint tabs no longer available.